# How to return an std::optional lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

How can I declare a function that returns an `std::optional` lambda? e.g.

```
<what_do_i_put_here?> foo(bool b) {
    if(b) return std::nullopt;
    return [](int) { ... };
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using `std::function<void(int)>` ? An `std::function` can be empty.

Comment: @MSalters I guess an optional lambda should have better performance than `std::function` (though the complexity might not be worth it)

Comment: @MSalters The actual return type is a class templated on a lambda. I can template it on `std::function`, but it would involve changing code in a lot of places and make code more verbose by adding `std::function` around each lambda that is currently deduced to its own type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using the ternary operator? It will automatically deduce the correct `optional` type

```
#include <optional>
auto foo(bool b) {
  return b ? std::nullopt : std::optional{[](int){}};
}
```

Comment: This is nice https://godbolt.org/z/5Mr5WW6r9

Comment: I didn't know this can be done. How does this work?

Comment: @Baruch: the third argument uses Class Template Argument Deduction, and the second argument can be converted to the (deduced) type of the third argument.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a level of indirection to deduce the type via `auto` and `decltype`:

```
#include <optional>

auto foo_impl(){
    return [](int){};
}

std::optional<decltype(foo_impl())> foo(bool b) {
    if(b) return std::nullopt;
    return foo_impl();
}
```

Comment: in c++17 you can do it without the extra function:https://godbolt.org/z/KMdY95nGs

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes but I didnt find a way that only creates the lambda in the branch that returns it. I suppose `[](int){}` is an oversimplified example while the actual lambda might be costly to construct or only possible to construct when `b == true`

Comment: A lambda isn't created as such unless it has captures, its just a function pointer

Comment: @AlanBirtles I know, and when it has captures creating it might involve costly copies

Comment: @AlanBirtles anyhow, its already in the other answer

Comment: @AlanBirtles: "just a function pointer" is an implementation detail. According to the Standard, a lambda has a unique type, which effectively means it cannot **be** a function pointer (but it can decay to one).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

auto f( bool b )
{
    auto l = [] { std::cout << "Hello World!";  };
    std::optional<decltype( l )> opt;

    if (b)
    {
        // some code
        opt = l;
    }
    else
    {
        // some other cod
    }

    return opt;
}

int main()
{
    ( *f( true  ) )( );
}
```

Another way is to use `std::function` with `std::optional` as for example

```
std::optional<std::function<void( int )>> g( bool b )
{
    if (b)
    {
        return std::function<void( int )>( []( int x ) { std::cout << x;  } );
    }
    else
    {
        return std::function<void( int )>( []( int x ) { std::cout << 2 * x; } );
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have updated the code.

Comment: `std::function` introduces unnecessary indirection.

Comment: @bitmask However the code becomes self-doccumented and such a construction is easy to use in other parts of the program and in different context,

Answer (score 0):

In the upcoming C++23 you can avoid an extra function while only constructing your lambda in case it is needed. Unfortunately, support for this is currently experimental:

```
#include <optional>

auto foo(bool const b) {
    return (b ? std::optional<bool>(true) : std::optional<bool>())
      .transform([](bool){
          return [](int){ return 42;};
      });   
}
```

([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eGacsPrx4) with gcc trunk)

This uses the new [`std::optional<T>::transform(F)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/transform) member function.

Comment: This seems like a more complicated variant of 康桓瑋's answer.